# How to fix '4864' result when using C++'s system() to execute 'tinymix' on Android microphone?

Tags: java, android, embedded, java-native-interface, microphone

Cpp's function system() not working properly with "tinymix" on android

I'm developing an application on android. One of the functionalities is the microphone. But I didn't found a native API to modify the microphone gain on Java, but I could do that by sending a terminal command "tinymix "ADC1 Volume" "" and it works. Than I decided to implement the gain changing using JNI to send the system() function of c++ to send the command I want programmatically. This is the part of the code:

```
`extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_oiton1_IHM_00024Audio_audioGain(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint value) {
    char buff[100];
    LOGD("jni", "value is %d", value);
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "tinymix \"ADC1 Volume\" %d", value);
    LOGD("jni", buff);
    int result = system(buff);
    LOGD("jni", "result is %d", result);
}`
```

When I execute, I got the desired value, the variable 'buff' is exactly as it need to be, but the result is '4864'. This is what I got on logcat:

---

05-24 12:12:25.238  2479  2479 D jni     : value is 10

05-24 12:12:25.245  2479  2479 D jni     : tinymix "ADC1 Volume" 10

05-24 12:12:25.252   436  3218 I AudioPolicyManagerCustom: FLAG None hence request for a primary output

05-24 12:12:25.254   436  3218 I AudioPolicyManagerCustom: FLAG None hence request for a primary output

05-24 12:12:25.330  2479  2479 D jni     : result is 4864

---

I tried different commands as 'reboot' or 'ls' 'cat ' and in this other cases, system() worked properly and the result was '0'. I would like to understand what may be happening and what could I do to solve this.

Comment: The value you get from `system` is a "wait status". If you pass 4864 to `WEXITSTATUS` to get the exit status code, you should get 19, which corresponds to ENODEV.

Comment: Does it mean that my device is busy? Is there anyway to make this command works? When I send manually exactly the same command it works properly, so what should I do?

Comment: AFAIK `tinymix` will return `ENODEV` if it fails to open the specified ALSA card (which in this case probably is card 0, since you didn't explicitly specify one). Why it failed to open the card, I don't know.